# ROS for Ubuntu 18.04 and x86

Tags: ros

I am trying to put ROS on my Intel-based Ubuntu 18.04 laptop and it seems by the documentation that they only made if for Amd?  Am I missing something.  It never finds any of the packages.

Unable to locate package ros-melodic-desktop-full.

Any solutions except formating the machine and going back to 14.04

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, Burf2000. Could you please clarify what you mean when you say it "never finds any of the packages?" If you're getting an error, please post the error verbatim. Please also post the contents of the configuration file(s) you're using to point your build to the packages. As it stands, you're having [trouble], but it's unclear beyond that what could be causing it.

Comment: Posted above, so I need to compile the source?

Answer (score 2):

amd64 is just a name for the 64-bit x86 architecture which the one used by both Intel and AMD processors, so you don't need to worry that it's AMD specific. Just go ahead and follow the usual steps for installing ROS (http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu).

Comment: I did, but it didn’t find any packages

Comment: Can you list the contents of the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list` file?